# i am getting error while using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gmail, nodemailer

```
here's my UserController.js where i am receiving user email and password as a post request

const User = require('../models/User');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

module.exports.User = (req, res) => {   
     if(req.body.password != req.body.confirm_password){
            res.redirect('back')
        }
        
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user){
        //error in creating the user
        if(err){console.log('error in creating the user');}

        //if user doesnot initially exist in the daatbase
        if(!user){
            User.create(req.body, function(err, user){
                if(err){console.log('error');}
                console.log('User created');
            })
            return res.send('<script>alert("User created")</script>');
        }
        else{
            console.log('User already present in the database');
            let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ 
                service: 'gmail', 
                host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                auth: { 
                    email: 'my_email',
                    pass: 'my_email_password'
                } 
            }); 
              
            let mailDetails = { 
                from: 'my_email', 
                to: req.body.email, 
                subject: 'from dhruv singhal as a project', 
                text: 'your data is successfully stored on our database'
            }; 
              
            mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function(err, data) { 
                if(err) { 
                    console.log(err); 
                } else { 
                    console.log('Email sent successfully'); 
                } 
            });
            res.send('<script>alert("your have already got mail from our side")</script>')
        }
    })
}


i am getting error as :-
```

/* Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:774:19)
at SMTPConnection.login (C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:438:38)
at C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:271:32
at SMTPConnection. (C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:209:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:315:20)
at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (C:\Us`enter code here`ers\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1303:14)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:932:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:739:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\dhruv singhal\Desktop\web_development_project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
code: 'EAUTH',
command: 'API'
}

```
i have enabled less secure apps on google please help

complete github code :-https://github.com/dhruv354/form.git*/
```

Comment: thank you very much , now it works fine after replacing 'email' with 'user'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `email: 'my_email'` I believe you need `user: 'my_email'`. See [this](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/examples/full.js) nodemailer example.

As mentioned in the other answer: before sending from your app for the first time, click this from the relevant Google account: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the "Captcha Challenge" on top of enabling the `less secure app`?

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha

Comment: it is not captcha challenge, just a toggle button to allow or disallow less secured apps

Comment: You need to do this Captcha Challenge on top of toggle the less secured apps. I was stucked at this step when I was playing with nodemailer.